reloading JavaFX shapes from a file
In code I inherited, the method below is in a serializable class (part of which is shown for context).
The following error is thrown when trying to read in the data containing this:

java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted;
java.io.NotSerializableException:
javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series

public class PCAGraph extends Graph implements Serializable {

    private String[] pcaColumnLabels; // store pca column name: PCA 1, PCA 2, ...
    private final List<String> eigenValues; // store eigen values
    private transient XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series;
    private transient BufferedReader bufferReader;
    private transient ScatterChart<Number, Number> pcaChart;
    private String line;
    private HashMap groupColors;
    private HashMap groupIcons;
    private transient MainController mainController;
    // group name -> with all associated graphs for different values of k
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>>> hiddenPCAGroups = new HashMap<>();
    private int labelClickCounter;
    private transient Label firstGroupLabel, secondGroupLabel;
    private Project project;

// detail omitted

    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>>> hiddenPCAGroups = new HashMap<>();


    public void hideGroup(String oldGroupName) {

        ArrayList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> hiddenGroups = new ArrayList<>(); // for various Ks

        // all pca charts
        for (int i=0; i<mainController.getPcaChartsList().size();i++){
            ScatterChart<Number, Number> chart = mainController.getPcaChartsList().get(i);

            for(int j=0;j<chart.getData().size();j++){
                XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = chart.getData().get(j);

                if (series.getName().equals(oldGroupName)) {

// removing the next line stops the hiddenness from
// being saved and gets rid of the exception on opening:
                    hiddenGroups.add(series); // save this series
                    chart.getData().remove(j); // remove it from the chart

                    // set color, icon, click event and legend for this chart
                    for(int k=0; k<chart.getData().size(); k++) {
                        // set legend
                        setLegend(chart, k, project.getPcaGroupColors(), project.getPcaGroupIcons());
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        hiddenPCAGroups.put(oldGroupName, hiddenGroups);
    }

// more detail omitted

}

If the line I indicate is commented out, the changes do appear on screen (other code missing from here does that) but saving does not save the hiddenness and it opens OK. If that line is put back, I get the exception thrown as indicated above.
I understand that a Hashmap is automatically serializable, but there could be some complications with serialising its contents, though ArrayList and Number are serializable not so?
This is one example of this kind in the code. Any help with tracking down the issue would are welcome.

A chart series is not a "JavaFX Shape".  JavaFX scene graphs, and nodes in general, especially complex elements such as graphs and even basic properties are not designed to be innately serializable using Java serialization tech.  I suggest you completely rethink your approach.

The classes underlying `tag:jfreechart-fx] implement [`Serializable`, but I've not used the feature.

I have never seen private transient MainController mainController;. Whenever I see MainController mainController in this type of way, I think -> bad project flow or structure.

Thanks for the comments. I am aware that a series is not a shape; it represents in this particular case which shapes are visible. I inherited this code and would like to get it working with minimal major changes.
I agree that  there are structural problems with the project; I managed to fix a lot of other issues.

"I am aware that a series is not a shape" -> Please fix the title then, because it is "reloading JavaFX shapes from a file", which is not what you are doing.

"would like to get it working with minimal major changes" -> That is fine, but to get specific debugging and bug diagnosis assistance you must provide a [mcve] - the shortest possible minimal code (including data, hardcoding it is fine) that reproduces the issue via copy and paste with no change or addition.  For something like this, it would require creating a custom example application that just reproduces the issue and does nothing else. It only needs to do the serialization that reproduces the failure.

"I understand that a Hashmap is automatically serializable, but there could be some complications with serialising its contents, though ArrayList and Number are serializable not so?" -> but the error indicates that you are trying to serialize an javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series, which is not serializable.  That is not related to those other types you mention.  Don't try to serialize objects which are not serializable.

Thanks for pointing out that  javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series is not serialisable – that would be why this HashMap isn’t.
My fix: copying the HashMap that was breaking to a simpler data structure while making the HashMap in the serialised class transient, and recreating it after file load.
I understand that a MWE is ideal but this is part of a complex app and the comments here have been helpful, thanks.

To summarise what I picked up from the comments,  javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series is not serialisable – that would be why this HashMap isn’t.
My fix: copying the HashMap that was breaking to a simpler data structure while making the HashMap in the serialised class transient, and recreating it after file load.
Thanks jewelsea for pointing this out.
